# ansible-playbook --extra-vars not accepting multiple params within bash script using $@

Tags: bash

I am wanting to run `ansible-playbook` from a bash script, where some parameters passed to the script will passed to Ansible in the form of `--extra-vars`.

```
EXTRA_VARS="--extra-vars '${@:2}'"
ansible-playbook \
-i hosts_$1 \
$EXTRA_VARS \
playbook.yml
```

I've put the command over multiple lines because in my script there are several long options passed to ansible and I want to improve readability.  If the user does not supply any variables beyond `$1`, then I just want to execute the playbook.

However, when I run something like:

```
./myscript inventory VAR1=KEY1 VAR2=KEY2
```

I get an error:

```
ERROR! the playbook: VAR2=KEY2' could not be found.
```

Am I not quoting `EXTRA-VARS` correctly when I set it?  Or is bash doing something funny when it expands the variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's demonstrate with an abstract example - I'll use `printf` so that newlines delimit each argument in the output.

Start with suitable `$*`:

```
set -- a b c d
```

Then:

```
vars="--vars '${@:2}'"
printf %s\\n $vars
```

The output is:

```
--vars
'b
c
d'
```

This shows that when `$vars` is expanded, the splitting happens at the space in the string, and between each of the interpolated elements of `$@`.

However, Bash supports array variables:

```
vars=(--vars "${@:2}")
printf %s\\n "${vars[@]}"
```

```
--vars
b
c
d
```

Or perhaps you wanted a single, space-separated argument:

```
vars=(--vars "${*:2}")
printf %s\\n "${vars[@]}"
```

```
--vars
b c d
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a variable; use an array!

```
extra_vars=("--extra-vars" "${@:2}")
```

Then pass it to the command with a quoted-array expansion, to not let the words split because of word-splitting:

```
ansible-playbook \
-i hosts_"$1" \
"${extra_vars[@]}" \
playbook.yml
```

See [BashFAQ/050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)- *I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!*

And never use single-quotes(`'`) around shell constructs (variable, array) that need to be expanded, use double-quotes(`"`) instead.